# iOS Firebase Analytics : It seems that firebase analytics does not collect user auto-collection information

Tags: ios, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics, idfa

My app is currently using google analytics. And try to introduce firebase analytics.

We have included the AdSupport.framework in the project as described in the manual to automatically collect user attributes using idfa.

However, when the filter is applied in the firebase analytics dashboard console, it appears as if it is not collected.

How do I automatically collect user information?

Is it just collecting apps downloaded from the App Store?

my develop environment:

- Xcode 9.4.1
- Firebase (5.4.0)
- FirebaseAnalytics (5.0.1)
- GoogleAnalytics (3.17.0)

Screenshot of no filter

[image]

Screenshot of apply filter

[image]

Comment: hi, did you manage to find a solution ? If you have found the solution, could you please share it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to check for automatic event logging on firebase console when in debug mode? if so then you might need to look at the `DebugView` instead of `StreamView`.