# Firebase does not collect age and gender data

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am linking my Android and iOS app to Firebase Analytics, and it seems to work well except I cannot collect the "automatic" information about the user, such as gender and age.

[image]

I can see some thousands of users, and I can also track custom events (like in-app purchases)

[image]

But in the same view, gender and age are not present.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51316630/ios-firebase-analytics-it-seems-that-firebase-analytics-does-not-collect-user) looks like the same, but the answer is not applicable: I used DebugView to test it and then deactivated it as per documentation.

of course, *View "All Users" audience* displays the same data.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you, but did you manage to find a solution ? Could you please share?

Comment: Hey man, it's been a long time but did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Does this question already have correct answer? What is the solution? I am still struggling too

Answer (score 2):

There are possible reasons:

1. [Google Signals](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9445345) isn't activated. Make sure that you have enabled Google Signals for your property, because Google signals are session data that Google associates with users who have logged in to their Google accounts and who have turned on Ads Personalization.
2. [Collection of Device Advertising IDs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=android) is disabled.
   Please ensure that the Collection of Device Advertising IDs is enabled, so that you will be able to see demographic and interest data on the Analytics dashboard since this is used to track user properties such as Age, Gender and Interests. Also, Analytics derives demographics and interests data from the Android Advertising ID or the iOS Identifier for Advertisers (IDFA).
3. `google-services.json` or dependencies are outdated

I have such problem. 1 and 3 solve it. You also can contact Firebase Support.

Answer (score 1):

According to this help center page on [automatically collected user properties](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=en),

> For iOS apps, the app must [collect IDFA](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318039) in order to automatically derive the Age, Gender, and Interests properties.

The link in there further clarifies:

> On iOS, the SDK collects the Advertising Identifier if it is available. For IDFA to be available, a developer has to link in the following libraries:
>
> - libAdIdAccess.a
> - AdSupport.framework

So you might want to check if you're including the necessary dependencies.

Comment: Ok but what about Android users? I have the same problem and I only have android app.

Comment: Please, let us know what about Android users. I am also facing same issue.

Comment: I would also Like to know what needs to be done for android users.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37403466/2410594), Firebase Analytics demographic reports is thresholded for privacy reasons. Once you have enough data -- at least 10 users per age/gender bracket -- data for that bracket will be shown.

Comment: I have 600 daily users still no gender and age information. I want to set an ad campaign and these numbers are important.